# Looking for a manga about a death game

Tags: story-identification, manga

The MC is a game developer? who gets transported into his game after being murdered by his own game character who came the real world though might not right after (little fuzzy).

The game is full of deadly children’s games like the werewolf game.

The game's main character (the same who kills the game maker) has a really sad backstory of being tortured as a human experiment and is really strong.

The MC gets shit for making his game really cruel to the characters.

The MC can eventually travel back to the real world while his sleeping in the game.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Sadly I can’t remember but I think colour